# NSString hasSuffix with wildcard, for example checking a year ends in 19xx or 20xx?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I want to check if an `NSString` ends with 19xx or 20xx, with the x's being any valid numbers.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why are people downvoting this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a predicate with a regular expression fits your bill:

```
NSString *str = @"2013";

NSPredicate *yearPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"SELF MATCHES '(19|20)[0-9]{2}'"];

BOOL matched = [yearPredicate evaluateWithObject: str];
```